# Break div out of overflow: hidden while retaining page structure

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to break a child element out of it's parent which holds overflow: hidden.

The reason for me restricting the dimensions of it's parent are purely for a JavaScript hack. I have tried positioning the child however this still breaks the pages structure and position fixed will be uneffective.

This is the closest I have got so far to achieving this:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div>
        <!-- Needs to be overflow hidden and 0 width -->
        <ul style="overflow: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
               <li>
                   <!-- Needs to be visible -->
                   <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                       Tab Content
                   </div>
               </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/0uwv3nyj/**

Does anyone know any kind of css hack or workout to solve this while retaining a standard block display to the element?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: I'm gonna tentatively say there's no way to do this. You're trying to set its container to 0px tall which means the next element won't respect the height of the inside `<div>` (it'll just rub up underneath the `<ul>`). I'd suggest that your JS hack thing can be done in a better way that doesn't stop you doing this. There's a reason your JS hack is called a hack - it breaks stuff

Comment: I thought this would be the case, am in the middle of moving the nodes in the js which is going to be much simpler but am curious if anyone can find a css hack.

Comment: If I understand correctly... you could [hide it differently like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hwa8u1x1/1/) using `position: relative` and `left: -9999px;` which can be reversed for the child ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but try setting the `ul` visibility to **hidden** and the `div` visibility to **visible**:

```
ul --> style="visibility:hidden; height:0;"
div --> style="visibility: visible;"
```